# Liang-Barsky in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, line

http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/viewing/leikkaus/intro.html

This is the site that I'm using to help me implement Liang-Barsky into C#.
Trouble is, I'm failing miserably at implementing it. I'd preferably be using this with XNA, so any help orienting around that would be greatly appreciated.

Any help?

Thanks, Ruirize.

Comment: Please show us the code you've got so far, and we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: There's the thing, I don't actually understand how to implement it; That's where I've been failing miserably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one available here: http://www.worldlingo.com/ma/enwiki/en/Liang-Barsky

Edit: That link appears to be dead. [Here is the google-cache copy, placed into pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NA01gacf).

Comment: I don't think that code is actually correct. If the test for any line fails, it fails the entire algorithm. I am not, however, an expert by any means. Someone with a better grasp of the algorithm (and vector math in general) may way to verify.

Comment: Well, it's been used in my game since that comment, and I've had no problems or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Fair enough. I had a unit test that was failing for it, gave it a half-assed once over, and then wrote that comment before searching out a new implementation. It is entirely possible that my unit test was simply incorrect. I scrubbed my unit tests with my new algorithm, or I'd go back and check (but you should go ahead and assume it was me).